# display user input using ajax in wordpress

Tags: plugins, php, ajax

I want  to display user input with ajax . but still is executed function **fail** in js file. I dont know where the problem might be. I read http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins and I saw http://pippinsplugins.com/using-ajax-your-plugin-wordpress-admin/

**EDIT**:I gave  `e.preventDefault();` on the top of jquery code in js .Its works (I received message from php file). but i dont know how its possible that the code works for me.

my form in main file

```
 <div id="wrap">
            <div id="chat" >
            </div>
            <div id="message"> 
                <form method="post" action="" id="sendformtoDB">
              <input  type='text' id="text" name="text"/> 
              <input id='send' type='submit' name="send"  class="button-primary" value='Submit' />
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

---

in my constructor add_action

```
add_action('wp_ajax_InsertIntoDB',array($this,'InsertIntoDB'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_InsertIntoDB',array($this,'InsertIntoDB'));
```

---

I load jquery library at first and the my js file

```
 public  function load_scripts() {
       wp_register_script( 'jquery', plugins_url( 'jq/jquery.js', __FILE__ ));
       wp_enqueue_scripts('jquery');
        wp_register_script( 'sendToDB',  plugins_url('jq/sendToDB.js',__FILE__ ),array( 'jquery' ));
        wp_enqueue_script('sendToDB');
        wp_localize_script( 'sendToDB', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
    }
```

---

php file

```
   public function InsertIntoDB(){
       if(isset($_POST['message'])){
     $messages=$_POST['message'];  
    # global $wpbdb;
     /* $wpbdb->insert('wp_userlogin',
              array(
                 "message"=>$message   
              ),
              array(
                  '%s'
              )
              );*/
     echo "$messages";
       }
        die();       
    }
```

---

js file

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {      
    $( " #sendformtoDB" ).submit( function() {
        var text;
         text = $( "#text" ).val();
         console.log(text);
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
     data:{"action":'InsertIntoDB',message:text},
     success:function(msg){
         alert(msg);
     }
    //  $(':input').not(":submit").val(''); 
   })

  .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
     alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus+jqXHR );
     });
 } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment. Try giving the datatype to the ajax call maybe this is due to json error.

Try adding datatype in your ajax as html for testing, then you can get into working path from these

```
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: ajaxurl,
     dataType: "html",
     data:{"action":'InsertIntoDB',message:text},
     success:function(msg){
         alert(msg);
     }
```

Also just try `ajaxurl` in the url field instead of `MyAjax.ajaxurl` even specifying datatype is not helping otherwise don't mess up with the url. Try the above and let me know what response you get in firebug.